# What is the difference b/w NS Classes and UI Classes? i read many documentations but didn't understand the required answer

Tags: ios, swift

detail description should be in the form of code also.

- i had read many documentations but not quite understand well.
- maybe, an example with code can help me with this.

Comment: NS is from NextStep. That's a really old thing, but most mac elements are that. UI is mostly for iOS and iPadOS.